# looping function every second

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im making a countdown timer and I want the time to refresh every second. Im using setInterval but it only seems to be running once instead of every second. What is wrong with my code?

```
var countDown = setInterval(function(){
$('#days').val(daysLeft);
$('#hours').val(hoursLeft);
$('#minutes').val(minLeft);
$('#seconds').val(secLeft);   
},1000);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EnigmaMaster/pyRR8/14/

Comment: It does run every second. The problem is in your values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recalculate the time left within the interval, otherwise you'll continue to set it to the same value.

Comment: ahhhh, thank you! I tend to make that mistake alot. Not the first time Ive spent time trying to figure out why something not working only to discover its cause i didnt include the variables in the function lol

Answer (score 2):

Your code was not updating the `currentDate` variable. I updated the code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyRR8/21/) and paste it here:

```
var endDay = new Date('May 24, 2012 11:30:00');

var countDown = setInterval(function(){
    var currentDate = new Date();

    var daysdecimal = (endDay - currentDate)/(1000*60*60*24);
    var daysLeft = Math.floor(daysdecimal);
    var hoursdecimal = (daysdecimal - Math.floor(daysdecimal))*24;
    var hoursLeft = Math.floor(hoursdecimal);
    var minLeft = 60 - currentDate.getMinutes();
    var secLeft = 60 - currentDate.getSeconds();

    $('#days').val(daysLeft);
    $('#hours').val(hoursLeft);
    $('#minutes').val(minLeft);
    $('#seconds').val(secLeft);   
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

want to look like this? I have updated your Jsfiddle

See here : http://jsfiddle.net/pyRR8/23/